# Debian+KDE. Set kde look for gtk applications?

Tags: debian, gnome, kde

Default look of gtk applications such as iceweasel is ugly, how can I change gtk applications to look like kde native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For KDE3**:  Make sure you have the package `gtk-qt-engine` (or `gtk-qt-engine-kde4` in case of an older Debian) installed on your system.  Open `kcontrol` and go to "Appearance & Themes"->"GTK Styles and Fonts".  Under "GTK Styles" select "Use another style" and chose "Clearlooks".

I suppose it's similar for KDE4.  Just have a look at `system-settings`.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention im running debian 6.0 wheezy, kde4.<br>
im looking in System Setting -> Appeareance -> don't see anything related to that :(

Comment: found an answer here: [link](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=54107). apt-get install lxappearance with qt-curve or gtk-oxygen

Answer (score 1):

This if the first topic that pops up when you ask stackoverflow.com about "kde gtk", so I'll write my answer here, even though its an old thread.

**`gkt-qt-engine`** seems no longer available for some linux distros, and it only handles GTK2 themes as far as i know. GTK3 applications need a package called **`kde-gtk-config`** to set their theme, I couldn't find this package for Ubuntu either but you can build it from the source (https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/kde-gtk-config/repository).

What you need (for ubuntu and possibly other debian based distros):

- git (to download the source)
- A C++ compiler (g++ recommended)
- cmake
- make
- kde development libraries (**`kde-workspace-dev`** on ubuntu)
- gtk 2 development libraries (**`libgtk2.0-dev`** on ubuntu)
- gtk 3 development libraries (**`libgtk-3-dev`** on ubuntu)

On ubuntu you can install them with:

```
apt-get install g++ git cmake make kde-workspace-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev
```

You need to download the source with git. To do this go to the folder you want to download it, and write:

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kde-gtk-config
```

This will download it to the the kde-gtk config directory. Now to build it, you type

```
cd kde-gtk-config
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr" ..
make
```

And finally to install and use it

```
make install
```

Keep the build directory and if you ever want to remove it just go there and type `make uninstall`. You may have to relog before you can see the changes in **System Settings -> Application Appearance**. If everything went well now you have a **Gtk Configuration** tab.

Answer (score 0):

for example to use oxy-white:

```
su
cd /usr/share/icons
mv oxy-black oxy-black.bak
ln -s oxy-white oxy-black
```

**K -> computer -> system settings -> keyboard & mouse -> mouse -> cursor theme -> oxygen white -> apply**